# Historical Prices of Gasoline vs. Crude Oil in the United States

Tags: united-states, price, comparison, crude-oil

If this question would be better placed on another site, please suggest.

I would like to know where I might obtain information on a monthly (even yearly) basis which compares the average price of crude (some benchmark) for that month to the average cost of gasoline  by state (in the U.S.)

I have noticed that when crude was dropping below seventy dollars per barrel, the price at the pump in certain places seemed to m e to be as high as when oil was around $80 per barrel or more.

Now that crude is over $80 per barrel, the prices at the pumps are continuing to rise well beyond what they were when crude was at this price months ago, or years ago.

Hence, I would like to see some actual comparisons if possible, so I ask---

Doe such data exist and where may I find it?

Comment: There's very little correlation between crude oil prices and what you pay ag the pump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S., the Energy Information Administration ([eia.gov](https://www.eia.gov)) is your best bet for this kind of data.

For instance, here are weekly retail gasoline prices by state/selected metro areas going back to the year 2000: https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_pri_gnd_a_epmr_pte_dpgal_w.htm

For oil, here are daily spot prices for WTI and Brent crude going back to 1986 and 1987, respectively: https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_pri_spt_s1_d.htm

Answer (score 0):

As a proxy for spot prices, you can look at UGA (United States Gasoline Fund) vs USO (United States Oil ETF).

The reason you're seeing elevated gasoline prices although crude prices have come down has to do with refinery capacity, which can't keep up with demand, and high refinery margins (crack spreads).

It would be helpful to know how you intend to use this data/information.

Comment: To add: refinery capacity limitation is exacerbated by the extreme heat in the south which limits the refinery use.

Comment: Also, my impression is that price at the pump always seems to go up the moment wholesale gas goes up, in anticipation of having to pay more for the next order, and come down only when they actually receive cheaper gas, so the retail peak tends to be broader than the wholesale peak. I wouldn't be shocked if the same thing happens between wholesale and crude.

Comment: @keshlam that, and competitive pressure once they start losing business to other gas stations in the area. In the meantime, they can pad their margins. Prices are generally quick to rise and slow to decline, as you mention.